# Need Realtime updating in JTextArea

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtextarea

I am trying to get this `JTextArea`, called `textArea`, to update while it is copying these photos but I can't quite seem to get it to work. I was using this code:

```
String name = "";
    int numberOfPicturesCopied = 0;
    while (pictures.isEmpty() == f) {
        try {
            File tmp = pictures.firstElement();
            name = tmp.getName();
            String filename = destination + Meta.date(tmp) + tmp.getName();
            Path source = tmp.toPath();
            File destFile = new File(filename);
            Path destination = destFile.toPath();
            Files.copy(source, destination,
                    StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
            textArea.append("Copied " + name + "\n");
            pictures.removeElementAt(0);
            numberOfPicturesCopied++;
        } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException faee) {
            textArea.append("Skipped " + name
                    + ": Picture Already In Computer\n");
        } catch (NoSuchFileException ncfe) {
            File tmp = pictures.firstElement();
            String filename = destination + Meta.date(tmp);
            File newDir = new File(filename);
            newDir.mkdir();
        } catch (IOException ee) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and then I changed it to this:

```
public void copyPictures(){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            String name = "";
            while(pictures.isEmpty() == f){
                try {
                    File tmp = pictures.firstElement();
                    name = tmp.getName();
                    String filename = destination + Meta.date(tmp) + tmp.getName();
                    Path source = tmp.toPath();
                    File destFile = new File(filename);
                    Path destination = destFile.toPath();
                    Files.copy(source, destination, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
                    textArea.append("Copied " + name + "\n");
                    pictures.removeElementAt(0);
                    numberOfPicturesCopied++;
                } catch(FileAlreadyExistsException faee){
                    textArea.append("Skipped " + name +": Picture Already In Computer\n");
                } catch (NoSuchFileException ncfe){
                    File tmp = pictures.firstElement();
                    String filename = destination + Meta.date(tmp);
                    File newDir = new File(filename);
                    newDir.mkdir();
                } catch (IOException ee) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

with the same outcome. Any suggestions?

Also, is there any way to get the text to come in at the top of text area?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.  Other things you tried can be indicated in a (for e.g.) `copyPictures2()` method. 2) It seems you are blocking the EDT.  Use a `SwingWorker`.

Comment: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Thread())` is flat out WRONG. You need to cleanly separate the File I/O work you want to do on a background thread from the updating of the Swing components, which should be done on the EDT.

Answer (score 1):

How to insert your text at the start is already answered. The other part of your question is the same as always ... you are performing heavy work on the Event Dispatch Thread, which is no longer able to perform repaints.

What you should do is perform the heavy work on a worker thread, and only update the UI on the EDT. You can for example use a `SwingWorker`, which is designed for this. Or even simpler, take your current code and with a few simple modifications

```
public void copyPictures(){
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(pictures.isEmpty() == f){
                try {
                    File tmp = pictures.firstElement();
                    final String name = tmp.getName();
                    String filename = destination + Meta.date(tmp) + tmp.getName();
                    Path source = tmp.toPath();
                    File destFile = new File(filename);
                    Path destination = destFile.toPath();
                    Files.copy(source, destination, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);

                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( 
                      new Runnable(){
                       public void run(){
                        textArea.append("Copied " + name + "\n");
                       }
                      }
                    );                    

                    pictures.removeElementAt(0);
                    numberOfPicturesCopied++;
                } catch(FileAlreadyExistsException faee){
                    textArea.append("Skipped " + name +": Picture Already In Computer\n");
                } catch (NoSuchFileException ncfe){
                    File tmp = pictures.firstElement();
                    String filename = destination + Meta.date(tmp);
                    File newDir = new File(filename);
                    newDir.mkdir();
                } catch (IOException ee) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.run();
}
```

See how the work is done on a separate `Thread` yet the UI is updated on the EDT. More information can be found in the [Swing Concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) or on SO (keyword for your search is `SwingWorker`, which will results in a heap of examples as this is a daily question)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking, the title seems to be saying that the text isnt updating, but your question seems to indicate that is isnt being inserted where you want it to be...

If its the latter, use the insert method instead

```
    textArea.insert("Copied " + name + "\n",0);
```

to put it at the top of the text area.